# Установка tensorflow на rasberian jessie

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

При попытке установить tensorflow на banana pi m64 возникает такая ошибка. Что делать?
Операционка: debian jessie;
версия питона: 3.4.2

> tensorflow-1.5.0-cp34-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых, я бы посоветовал Вам прочесть [документацию](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources).

Если вы уже это сделали, то попробуйте собрать tenorflow под свою платформу.

Для начала клонируйте tensorflow репозиторий командой `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow` (если у вас не установлен git, установите его командой `sudo apt install git`)

Затем Вам следует установить [bazel](https://bazel.build/).

Затем `numpy`, `wheel` с помощью *pip*-а `pip install numpy` (и wheel)
Затем Вам нужно запустить `sudo apt install pythonX-dev`, где X - версия python

Если Вам потребуется поддержка GPU, читайте инструкцию от tenserflow на оф. сайте.

Затем запустите `cd tensorflow && ./configure` и следуйте инструкциям в запросах.

Затем Вам придётся собрать пакет `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Далее выпейте чашечку кофе или погуляйте.

Следующий шаг - создание *.whl*
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`

И последний шаг - установка в python:
`sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.5.0-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Попробую сделать всё по вашей инструкции. Вы еще дали битую ссылку на инструкцию по установке bazel, или он ставится как обычно install bazel?

Comment: При установке bazel появилась такая вот ошибка... ERROR: JDK not found, please set $JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Установи java. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Либо в терминале sudo apt install oracle-java8

Comment: Поставил java но при сборке bazel вот такая вот ошибка появилась
'ERROR: /home/pi/tf/bazel-0.4.4/src/main/protobuf/BUILD:25:2: Java compilation in rule '//src/main/protobuf:extra_actions_base_java_proto' failed: Worker process sent response with exit code: 1'

Comment: Это уже тема для другого вопроса.